# Using R to scrape nested XML data

Tags: xml, r, xpath, web-scraping

Hello I'm quite new to R and I'm trying to scrape a web site for some data. The problem is that the data is stored inconsistently.

Sometimes I see:

```
<div class = "text">   The text I want   </div>
```

And other times I see:

```
<div class = "text"><div class = "text">   The text I want   </div></div>
```

So far I'm using the XML package and the following R code:

```
doc = htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T)
text = xpathSApply(doc, "//*/div[@class='text']", xmlValue)
```

The problem is that this code will count "The text I want" twice when it comes across the second example, because it finds the `<div class>` attribute twice. I only want to count it once because it only appears once.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xtext <- "<div class = \"text\">   The text I want   </div>
</div><div class = \"text\"><div class = \"text\">   The text I want   </div></div>"
doc <- htmlParse(xtext)
xpathSApply(doc,"//*/div[@class='text']/text()")

#[[1]]
#   The text I want    

#[[2]]
#   The text I want
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to count occurrences, then you should be able to find all nodes

```
all_text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//*/div[@class='text']", xmlValue)
```

and doubled nodes

```
doubled_text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//*/div[@class='text']/div[@class='text']", xmlValue)
```

then subtract the length of one from the other to get a true reflection.

Comment: Hello, I don't actually want to count occurrences (apologies for the confusion) - I want to return "The text I want" everywhere it is found on the web page. But I don't want to duplicate occurrences when it is found within nested `<div class>` statements